# MySQL 5.5 Database design. Problem with friendly URLs approach

Tags: mysql, database-design, insert, relational-database, friendly-url

I have a maybe stupid question but I need to ask it :-)

My Friendly URL (furl) database design approach is fairly summarized in the following diagram (**InnoDB** at **MySQL 5.5** used)

[image: diagram]

Each item will generate as many furls as languages available on the website. The furl_redirect table represents the controller path for each item. I show you an example:

```
item.id = 1000
item.title = 'Example title'
furl_redirect = 'item/1000'
furl.url = 'en/example-title-1000'
furl.url = 'es/example-title-1000'
furl.url = 'it/example-title-1000'
```

When you insert a new item, its furl_redirect and furls must be also inserted. The problem appears becouse of the (necessary) unique constraint in the furl table. As you see above, in order to get unique urls, I use the title of the item (it is not necessarily unique) + the id to create the unique url. That means the order of inserting rows should be as follow:

```
1. Insert item -- (and get the id of the new item inserted) ERROR!! furl_redirect_id must not be null!!
2. Insert furl_redirect -- (need the item id to create de path)
3. Insert furl -- (need the item id to create de url)
```

I would like an **elegant solution** to this problem, but I can not get it!

Is there a way of getting the **next AutoIncrement value** on an InnoDB Table?, and is it recommended to use it?
Can you think of another way to ensure the **uniqueness of the friendly urls** that is independent of the items' id? Am I missing something crucial?

Any solution is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get an auto-increment in InnoDB, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).  Whether you should use it or not depends on what kind of throughput you need and can achieve.  Any auto-increment/identity type column, when used as a primary key, can create a "hot spot" which can limit performance.

Another option would be to use an alphanumeric ID, like bit.ly or other URL shorteners.  The advantage of these is that you can have short IDs that use base 36 (a-z+0-9) instead of base 10.  Why is this important?  Because you can use a random number generator to pick a number out of a fairly big domain - 6 characters gets you 2 billion combinations.  You convert the number to base 36, and then check to see if you already have this number assigned.  If not, you have your new ID and off you go, otherwise generate a new random number.  This helps to avoid hotspots if that turns out to be necessary for your system.  Auto-increment is easier and I'd try that first to see if it works under the loads that you're anticipating.

You could also use the base 36 ID and the auto-increment together so that your friendly URLs are shorter, which is often the point.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider another ways to deal with your project.
At first, you are using "en/" "de/" etc, for changing language. May I ask how does it work in script? If you have different folders for different languages your script and users must suffer a lot. Try to use gettext or any other localisation method (depends on size of your project).

About the friendly url's. My favorite method is to have only one extra column in item's table. For example:

```
Table picture
id, path, title, alias, created
Values:
1, uploads/pics/mypicture.jpg, Great holidays, great-holidays, 2011-11-11 11:11:11
2, uploads/pics/anotherpic.jpg, Great holidays, great-holidays-1, 2011-12-12 12:12:12
```

Now in the script, while inserting the item, create alias from title, check if the alias exists already and if does, you can add id, random number, or count (depending on how many same titles u have already).

After you store the alais like this its very simple. User try to access

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/picture/great-holidays
```

So in your script you just see that user want to see picture, and picture with alias great-holidays. Find it in DB and show it.

Comment: "Actually your system in whole doesn't seems to be very efficient." - probably worth reviewing that comment as it could be seen as being overly critical. You might consider answering the question first and then providing some feedback on how to improver the efficiency.

Comment: Ok, my bad, i didn't know people here are sensitive :) I didn't said it is bad, just saying that might consider another ways. So, I will edit it, if that is possible. Sorry to all